# Python Naive Bayes Classifier trained on Movie Review Corpus to test on Tweets

Tags: python, twitter, nlp, nltk, naivebayes

```
import nltk.classify.util
import csv
from nltk.classify import NaiveBayesClassifier
from nltk.corpus import movie_reviews

def word_feats(words):
    return dict([(word, True) for word in words])

negids = movie_reviews.fileids('neg')
posids = movie_reviews.fileids('pos')

negfeats = [(word_feats(movie_reviews.words(fileids=[f])), 'neg') for f in negids]
posfeats = [(word_feats(movie_reviews.words(fileids=[f])), 'pos') for f in posids]

negcutoff = len(negfeats)*3/4
poscutoff = len(posfeats)*3/4

trainfeats = negfeats[:negcutoff] + posfeats[:poscutoff]
testfeats = negfeats[negcutoff:] + posfeats[poscutoff:]
print 'train on %d instances, test on %d instances' % (len(trainfeats), len(testfeats))

classifier = NaiveBayesClassifier.train(trainfeats)
print 'accuracy:', nltk.classify.util.accuracy(classifier, testfeats)
classifier.show_most_informative_features()
```

I am very new to Python and am trying to perform sentiment analysis on Tweets. I am using the Naive Bayes Classifier that is built into the NLTK package. I am testing it on the movie review corpus and want to test in on tweets I have stored into a .txt or .csv file using Tweepy. Can anyone help figure out how to test this classifier off the tweets in my output file? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Simply load the tweets:

```
f = open('tweets.txt', 'r')
data = f.readlines()
testfeats = word_feats([tweet.split(' ') for tweet in data]) # for file with tweets separated by line
```

Then you can use your word_feats method to extract the features (you could probably use a CountVectorizer instead).

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. I added in the following >>>f = open('tweets.txt', 'r')
>>>data = f.readlines()   >>>testfeats = word_feats(data) but received a "ValueError: too many values to unpack" error. What do you think caused this?

Comment: You'll probably need to parse the text file. What's the format?

Comment: I have two different formats for the same data both in separate text files.  They contain just the text of the tweets, and in one the tweets are separated by a delimiter ",, " and in the other by line breaks.

Comment: You need to tokenize the tweets. Either use `string.split(' ')` (see my example) or you use a tokenizer like NLTK's.